# Linq to xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Scenario:

1. Grid view  gets populated in WPF window.
2. Having a static list in code behind.(which i want to get from a xml file).

Trying to move the static list into an xml file.For that i created a ml file in the following format

```
<customers>
<customer Name="abc"/>
<customer Name="def"/>
</customers>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Xdocument doc=Xdocument.load("customers.xml");
var customerList = (from e in doc.Descendants("Cusomters")

                            select new
                            {
                                CustomerName = e.Attribute("Name").Value
                            }).ToList();
```

I am unable to get the customer names from the xml file to the customerList.I would appreciate if someone can help me to move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Cusomters"` is spelled incorrectly, should be `"Customers"`.

Obviously this is not the code your are using since it doesn't even compile.  It should be this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "customers.xml" );
var customerList = (from e in doc.Descendants( "customer" )
        select new
        {
            CustomerName = e.Attribute( "Name" ).Value
        }).ToList();
```

You really should mention the fact that it won't compile.  That, or you copied it in by hand incorrectly, which doesn't help us help you either.

The logical problem here is that you are asking for all `Customers` tags, note the `s` at the end.  You really want to look for `Customer` tags, which have a `name` attribute.  `Customer*s*` is simply the top level group.

Answer (score 2):

Use `customer` instead of `Cusomters` (XML is case-sensitive):

```
from e in doc.Descendants("customer")
```

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want a `List<string>` so you don't need to project to an anonymous class - also there is a typo in your query (`"Cusomters"`):

```
var customerList = (from e in doc.Descendants("Customer")
                    select e.Attribute("Name").Value).ToList();
```

or with extension method syntax:

```
var customerList = doc.Descendants("Customer")
                      .Select( e => e.Attribute("Name").Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive always used :

```
doc.root.elements("Customer")
```

for small snippets like this.

Comment: -1 Descendants works as advertised (documented).  Better to understand why your code didn't work than to say "Oh well, this way doesn't work for some reason, we'll just use this instead".

Comment: and that deserved a -1... jesus... you could have just ignored it, it was still a viable option.  My problems with descendent's are not  anyone else's, I was just making a passing comment... some people ... sheesh ... get a grip.

Comment: It's not personal, I just don't think it's a good answer. You are making a claim that using `.Descendants` doesn't work reliably, yet you don't explain why.  That only serves to confuse a beginner.  On top of that, it exhibits a "voodoo" type coding style, i.e., "This doesn't work, we don't know why, just do it this way".  That's never a good thing in a code base.

Comment: I would also add that the OP's problem has absolutely nothing to do with the use of `.Descendants`, it is simply a typo.  Using `.Descendants` works as expected.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, BUT..  using the code posted is still a viable option, it will work and it will get the result that the OP wants, therefore -1 is not justified, leaving it at a 0 maybe, or giving a -1 if i'd given a completely bogus code snippet that would never work fair enough, but giving a -1 for something that actually works isn't justified in my opinion.

Comment: Now as you can see, my answer definitely doesn't justify a -1, because there's no mention of 'Descendants' and it's a viable solution to the question asked.

Comment: I would still point out more clearly that the real problem is the typo, but meh.  Downvote removed.

Comment: Agreed, the main problem was the Typo, something I must confess I did not spot until after I'd posted, oh and thank you.